# Django - How to go back to previous url

Tags: python, django

I have multiple todo lists on different pages in an app written in python. I dont want to use delete and update functions over and over again. I want to use one for all pages. In update and delete functions, I can redirect to a certain page after code execution. But its not dynamic. How can I make it dynamic?

```
def updateTodo(request, pk):
task = Todo.objects.get(id=pk)
form = FormTodo(instance=task)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = FormTodo(request.POST, instance=task)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('/page_path')
context = {'form':form}
return render(request, 'update_task.html', context)
```

What should I write instead of page_path so that it redirects to the page it comes from?

I thought going back to the latest page would be an option but guess what? I couldnt do it either. Also, would going back create an error or something? since I'm updating an entry.

Any suggestions ?

(I saw some options with selenium but it seems to work for chrome or selected browsers only. I'd like to avoid using selenium if there is another way)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use names in your url paths then you can do `return reverse('url-name')`
[Reverse resolution of URLs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/urls/#reverse-resolution-of-urls)
But without seeing more and having more context it's a bit difficult to know what you want to achieve.